Модификаторы доступа в Java (Зачем нужен public в данном случае)?
Если метод задать так:
public void eat(){
    System.out.println("Animal is eating");
}

или так
void eat(){
    System.out.println("Animal is eating");
}

В чём разница между этими двумя методами? Какую роль здесь играет модификатор доступа public? Что будет, если его не написать? Метод вызывается в обоих случаях.

Разница в том, кто сможет вызывать этот метод

Во втором случае метод будет виден только классам внутри этого же пакета, но не из других пакетов.

по умолчанию, в java, модификатор доступа: package-private

Этот вопрос похож на: Модификаторы доступа в Java. Если вы считаете его другим, пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос, чётко обозначив отличие и/или почему ответы на вопрос не помогли в вашем случае.

Метод класса можно вызывать как внутри самого класса, так и за пределами его. Все, что нужно для вызова метода - это ссылка на объект этого класса. Модификаторы доступа ограничивают видимость тех или иных методов за пределами класса, а также за пределами пакета в котором этот класс определен. Делается это с целью инкапсуляции, делая часть методов недоступными извне.
Модификатор public даёт доступ всем объектам возможность вызывать метод. В то время как без этого модификатора доступ имеют только классы находящиеся в том же пакете, что и данный класс. Соответственно он называется package private по умолчанию.
Для полного понимания следует читать Java Tutorial.
